# How to check google street view is available or not for a perticular location coordinate

Tags: ios, ipad, google-maps, google-street-view

I am showing google street view from my ios app for a perticular location using Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 1.4.0.4450.
It works fine if street view is available.

My question is if street view is not available how to check it?

There is a class GMSPanoramaService. It contains a public member method. I think this can be useful. 
- requestPanoramaNearCoordinate:callback:
Retrieves information about a panorama near the given coordinate.

But how to use it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

You may use this rude method

```
-(void)isStreetViewAvailable:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location completionBlock:    (NWisStreetViewCompletionBlock)completionBlock
 {
 NSString *loc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.10f,%.10f&", location.latitude, location.longitude];
 NWisStreetViewCompletionBlock completeBlock = [completionBlock copy];


 NSString *connectionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://cbk0.google.com/cbk?output=json&ll=%@", loc];
 NSLog(@"connect to: %@",connectionString);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:connectionString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation;
operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    //NSLog(@"%@", JSON);

    NSLog(@"%@", JSON);

    if([JSON objectForKey:@"Location"] == nil)
        completeBlock(@"", nil);

    //NSLog(@"panoId: %@",[[json objectForKey:@"Location"] objectForKey:@"panoId"]);

    completeBlock([[JSON objectForKey:@"Location"] objectForKey:@"panoId"], nil);



} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {

    NSMutableDictionary* details = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [details setValue:[error description] forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
    // populate the error object with the details
    NSError *err = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"world" code:200 userInfo:details];

    completeBlock(NO, err);
}];

[operation start];



}
```

Comment: This code is incomplete, NWisStreetViewCompletionBlock is not defined

Comment: typedef void (^NWisStreetViewCompletionBlock)        (NSString *panoIdOfPlace, NSError *error);

Comment: Sure, thought that it is rather easy :)